# Finding grid nodes a line passes through

Tags: geometry, integer-programming

For 2D grid pathfinding, I want to do a quick broadphase to check if there is a direct path from the start to the target by conceptually checking all nodes touching the line segment formed by connecting the start and target nodes.

Is there an efficient way to iterate over each grid node between 2 grid nodes? If there isn't, would this broadphase be worth it?

Note: Grid nodes are stored in a 2D array like Node[,]. They each store a boolean describing whether one can be walked on or not, and also store their position on the grid. The information supplied for pathfinding (and this broadphase) is 2 grid nodes: a start and end node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid points lying on the line connecting point $a$ with position $(x_1, y_1)$ to point $b$ with position $(x_2, y_2)$ can be found from the slope, which is given by $\frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$.

In the example below, $a=(3,2)$, $b=(28,12)$, and the slope is $\frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}=\frac{12-2}{28-3}=\frac{2}{5}$.

So $a + k (5,2)$ for $k=1,\ldots$

---

[image: Plot]

Comment: How would I check each node on the way from a to b? For example, detecting that pathfinding would be needed if (5,2) and (5,3) were unwalkable.

Comment: @JPtheK9: I don't understand the question. $(5,3)$ is not on the straight line $ab$. I am afraid we are using different vocabularies, making communication difficult.

Comment: What I was trying to do was to check if a direct path is available.Solved the issue with Breesenham's Algorithm. Thanks for the answer and since yours is the only one, I'll accept it and close the question

Comment: That's kind of you. I didn't understand you were seeking a *digital* straight line. Glad you discovered [Bresenham's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm).